# Why would both a parent and child class implement the same interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I inherited some legacy Java (1.4) code and this design decision appears regularly. I can't understand if there's any purpose or reason to it.

```
public interface SoapFacade extends iConfigurable{ }

public class SoapFacadeBase implements SoapFacade{
...
}

public class SoapFacadeImpl extends SoapFacadeBase implements SoapFacade{
...
}
```

As I understand interfaces (and my experimentation has reinforced), there is no purpose to having both the parent and the child implement the same interface. In this scenario, everything from `SoapFacade` is implemented in `SoapFacadeBase`, but the method in `iConfigurable` is implemented in `SoapFacadeImpl`. However, that doesn't create a need to have `SoapFacadeImpl` implement `SoapFacade`.

Is there something I don't know about interfaces that would give this pattern some purpose or benefit? Are there underlying costs beyond lack of clarity that should drive refactoring it? Or should it simply be refactored for clarity/simplicity?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> **As I understand interfaces (and my experimentation has reinforced), there is no purpose to having both the parent and the child implement the same interface.**

No. Technically, it is completely redundant.

It *does* however document the fact that you intend `SoapFacadeImpl` to be a `SoapFacade` and it ensures that you get a compile error, if you (or someone else) decides to remove `implements SoapFacade` from the base class.

You see this pattern everywhere in the standard Java Collections API. `ArrayList` implements `List` even though its base class (`AbstractList`) already, does. Same holds for `HashSet` / `AbstractSet` and the `Set` interface.

Comment: It has some side effects. If you want to replace SoapFacade with SomethingElse (not renaming SoapFacade, replacing with a totally different interface) you'll have to replace it everywhere, and also the "Refactor" features of some IDEs (as Eclipse) won't help you. More, if you pass the code to other people, they may spend minutes in finding why they're getting compile errors on children classes (like: wtf... who the hell wrote this)

Comment: +1 That does give me something else to think about with that. From the posted sample, everything from `SoapFacade` is implemented in the base class; thus I am more inclined to remove the `implements SoapFacade` from the derived class so as to obscure the details of `SoapFacade` from the child.

Comment: @Giacormo, What do you mean by "getting compile errors on children classes"??

Answer (score 13):

If you use the interface also as a marker. `Class.getInterfaces();` will only return directly instanced interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find that design pointless. Implemented interfaces, as you stated, are just inherited, so there's no need to copy and paste "implements SomeInterface" on the children classes.
It's not clearer, smarter, or whatsoever...

Comment: It does guarantee that the subclass implements the interface, even if the base class gets refactored and no longer implements the interface. It also serves a documentation purpose. It should also be noted that it is used just about everywhere in the standard collections API. See my answer.

Answer (score -2):

It is nonsense, don't do it.

Especially in a public API like java collections. It's absolutely nonsense.