# Parent and child classes implementing a common interface, repeatedly

Tags: java, inheritance, ejb-2.x, implements

Today i found in my codes what appears to be a child class implementing an interface that the parent class is already inheriting.

May i know if this has any adverse side effects or intentions, as i am working on to remove it from the child class as i believe this could have been an accidental mistake, or perhaps am i missing something?

In the child class:

```
public class ProductServiceBean
  extends GenericSessionBean
  implements javax.ejb.SessionBean
```

In the parent class:

```
// Compiled from GenericSessionBean.java (version 1.2 : 46.0, super bit)
public abstract class weblogic.ejb.GenericSessionBean 
  extends weblogic.ejb.GenericEnterpriseBean 
  implements javax.ejb.SessionBean
```

Note that in both child and parent, the classes do implement the `javax.ejb.SessionBean`.

Comment: Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668429/why-would-both-a-parent-and-child-class-implement-the-same-interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing `implements javax.ejb.SessionBean` from *only* the `ProductServiceBean` class will have no effect, since the fact that the class implements the interface is inherited from the parent `GenericSessionBean` class.

There is also no harm in including it in the child class, it's just a redundant declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Having both the child and the parent implement the same Interface has no additional effect. It is equivalent to having the parent only implement that interface.