# Do i need to implement the interface from parent class again

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I have a **interface** `ShippingProduct` and 2 **classes** `ShippingProductStandard`, `ShippingProductGurtmass`.

The class `ShippingProductStandard` implements the interface `ShippingProduct`.

```
public class ShippingProductStandard implements ShippingProduct {
...
}
```

Now i want that, the class `ShippingProductGurtmass` extends `ShippingProductStandard` and implements `ShippingProduct`. Do i need to implement the interface `ShippingProduct`  like that:

```
public class ShippingProductGurtmass extends ShippingProductStandard implements ShippingProduct {
...
}
```

Or do i only need to extend the class `ShippingProductStandard` and it will implement the interface `ShippingProduct` from the parent class automatic?

```
public class ShippingProductGurtmass extends ShippingProductStandard{
...
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5668477/6507689. Look on stack first before posting of question~.

Comment: no, you don't need to implement the interface again

Comment: @R.Zagórski Thanks I was looking for one. FYI, prefer to flag as duplicate, this is the preferred to way to link to a potential duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to write a relationship like this

```
public class ShippingProductGurtmass extends ShippingProductStandard implements ShippingProduct {
...
}
```

you can use only this code to call the overrided/implemented methods (in ShippingProductGurtmass)  of Interface ShippingProduct

```
public class ShippingProductGurtmass extends ShippingProductStandard{
...
}
```

Relation hierarchy is automatically generated. You can Imagine it like as the java Concept says Object is a parent Class for all classes written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the class ShippingProductStandard and it will implement the interface ShippingProduct from the parent class automatically. You may override those methods if you like.